# Mysterious iptable rules in centos 8

Tags: centos, iptables

I have following iptable rules on system restart. They are not defined in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

I am unable to figure out where they are coming from. In fact the rules defined in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` are not even in the table so that is ruled out (see last section).

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
```

I have removed `firewalld` and `nftables` to debug the issue but no difference. I disabled `iptables` also.

```
[root@dan ~]# systemctl status firewalld
Unit firewalld.service could not be found.
[root@dan ~]# systemctl status nftables
Unit nftables.service could not be found.
[root@dan ~]# systemctl status iptables
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I suspected docker but that is also disabled

```
[root@dan ~]# systemctl status docker
systemctl status dockerdocker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
```

I also tried to find matching text/rule in `/etc` but no luck

```
[root@dan ~]# find /etc -type f -exec grep "192.168.122.0" {} /dev/null \;
```

If I restart `iptables`, it is correctly loading from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and hence issue seems to be in the booting sequence.

```
[root@dan ~]# systemctl restart iptables
[root@dan ~]# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any idea or insight on how to debug this?

Comment: insight: 192.168.122.0/24 (just google for it)

Comment: phew! I was close with docker! thanks :)

Comment: Imho, you should answer yourself to your question or delete it, since it's not needed anymore.